# java error:inconvertible types required int

Tags: java, netbeans

what is wrong with this code??

```
int  amount= (int)  amountSpnr.getValue();  // 1
float total = (float) productData[3]*amount; // 2
total2pay+=total;
totalFld.setText(total2pay+"");
model.addRow(new Object[]{productData[0], productData[1],productData[2],productData[3], amount, total});`
```

says :

> inconvertible types
>   (for the 1st line)- required `int` found `Object`
>   (for the 2nd line)- required `float` found `Object`

What can i do?

Comment: What is `amountSpnr` and `productData`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot cast Objects in Java to primitive (except for their respective wrapper classes).

Try using this:

```
    Object obj1 = amountSpnr.getValue();
    Object obj2 = productData[3];

    if (obj1 instanceof Integer) {
        int amount = (Integer) obj1; // 1
    }

    if (obj2 instanceof Float) {
        float total = (Float) obj2; // 2
        total *= amount;
    }
```

In the above case, `Object` will be down-casted to `Integer` type, which will then be unboxed to primitive integer. Same is the case with `Float`.

Note: Be sure to add `instanceof` check before you perform downcasting just to make sure that you do not end up getting `CastCastException`.

Comment: Of which class is `amountSpnr` and `productData` in your opinion?

Comment: I still have an error with the 2nd code line : required int found Object

Comment: Check what is the return type of amountSpnr.getValue(); If it is returning int, then you need not add any cast while assigning. By the error it seems that your object is not of the type int. In that case you cannot cast it to int or Integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to tranform your Object into a int primitive you have to follow 2 steps :

First make sure your object has the good type. 
Cast it with `(Integer)` or `(Float)`. You can use `instanceof` if you're not sure of the type returned by `getValue` (case 1) or by you array (case 2)

Then use `.intValue()` or `.floatValue()`.

Example :

`int amount=((Integer)amountSpnr.getValue()).intValue();`

`float total = ((Float) productData[3]*amount).floatValue();`